# Finding kernel of a map in a minimal free resolution of a graded ideal

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, homological-algebra, graded-modules, free-modules

Let $I=(x_{1}^{2}-x_{2}x_{3},x_{3}^{2}x_{4},x_{1}x_{2}x_{3},x_{4}^{3})\subset S=K[x_{1},x_{2},x_{3},x_{4}]$ be an ideal. I am trying to compute its minimal graded free resolution.
Since $I$ has four generators three of degree $3$ and one of degree $2$ so $F_{0}=S(-2)\oplus S^{3}(-3)$. That is
$\cdots\rightarrow S(-2)\oplus S^{3}(-3)\rightarrow I\rightarrow 0$.
Next we need to find the kernel of $S(-2)\oplus S^{3}(-3)\rightarrow I$. Please help to find the kernel and complete the resolution.

Comment: I know its minimal free resolution. I just want to learn how to compute it.

Comment: I don't know how to find all relations. Writing $f_1 = x_1^2 - x_2x_3$, etc, I got $x_1x_4^3 f_1 - x_4^3f_3 - x_1^2x_2^2 f_4 = 0$. But I believe there are other relations and it's probably not easy to know when there is no more relations, so the best is probably to do it by computer or use an algorithm with e.g Gröbner basis.